# EntityManager query by joinColumn

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager, joincolumn

I have a `Login` entity and a `Customer` entity. `Login.username` is a foreign key in the customer table. Hence the following line in the Java `Customer` POJO

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "username", nullable = false)
private Login login;
```

My question is this: Is there a simple way to query the `customer` table using `username`? Or must I first fetch `login` by `username` and then `customer` by `login`?

Here is the JPA criteria query. And, yes, I would prefer to use criteria query.

```
public Customer getCustomerByUsername(String username) throws EntityNotFoundException {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Customer> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Customer.class);
    Root<Customer> root = criteriaQuery.from(Customer.class);
    Path<String> path = root.<String>get("username");
    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(path, username));
    return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
}
```

The line `Path<String> path = root.<String>get("username")` is throwing an exception saying that `username ... is not present.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct solution with JPQL is

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.login.username = :username");
    q.setParameter("username", username);
    return (Customer) q.getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Customer c JOIN Login l ON c.login=l WHERE l.username = :username");
q.setParameter("username",username);
List<Customer> customerList = q.getResultList();
```

There are a few tricks to keep in mind: this all is about the objects, and not the underlying DB. So the names represent classes, instances, and fields, and they are all CaseSensitive... The error you got meant that your Customer class didn't have a userName field - which is true, since Login has that... Sadly, I can't test it, but the logic and intentions should be clear.

Comment: After much research, I finally caved in and decided to use your suggestion. I get the following error: `... Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.username = :username], line 1, column 33: unknown state or association field [username] of class [com.mysite.Customer].` Recall that my original problem is the `Login` and not `username` is a field in `Customer`.

Comment: I figured it out. As I mention in my response, the following works fine: `SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.login.username = :username`. Up vote for helping.

Comment: @kasavbere hmm, this easy and nice solution didn't occur to me, even though I've been using JPA for years. But this is **exactly** how JPA is to be used! You can accept your own answer, it is allowed!